# How to pass props from child component (addform) to main app component using programmatic routing in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to navigate to another component when searching, I need to get an array or the results of the firesearch function and send them to main app component when the function is triggered.

I tried to push history but i do not get the props that I needed, i tried to use router but i got push is undefined

update: it seems that the repos component is not receiving the list of repos from addform component when sending them in the route, the location is undefined i got error ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

any help with this

here is the child (addform) component:

````
     state = {
         username: null,
         repos: []
     }
     constructor(props) {
         super(props)
       }

     fireSearch = (username) => {
         axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/'+ username +'/repos').then(res => {
                   this.setState({

                       repos: res.data

                   })
                   this.props.history.push({
                     pathname:  '/' + username,
                     state: {
                         repos: res.data
                     }
                 })
               })

       }

     handleChange = (e) => {

         this.setState({
           username: e.target.value
         })
        }
     handleSubmit = (e) => {

         e.preventDefault();


           }
 render(){
     return(
         <div className="container">
             <form className="center" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             <h1 className="center">Repositories</h1>
       <input type="text" className="center" id="usrname" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
       <button onClick={() => this.fireSearch(this.state.username)}><img src={submiticon} alt='submit icon'/>Submit</button>
     </form>
         </div>
     )
 }
 }
 export default withRouter(Addform) ```



and here is the main app component:
````

````
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    username: null,
    repos:[],
    issues:[]
  }


  enterIssues = (urlstring) => {

    axios.get('https://api.github.com/' + urlstring).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        issues: res.data
      })
      }

    )

  }
  render(){

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
    <Route path='/' render={() => (<Addform />)} />
    <Route exact path='/:username' render={() => (<Repos repos={this.state.repos} enterIssues={this.enterIssues} />)} />
    {/* <Repos repos={this.state.repos} enterIssues={this.enterIssues} /> */}
    <Route exact path='/:username/:repository' component={() => <Issues issues={this.state.issues} />}  />

    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

}
export default App; ```
````

here is the repos component:

````
      state = {
          repos:[]

      }

      componentDidMount(){
          console.log(this.props);

            this.setState({


              repos: this.props.repos
           })    

      }
      render(){
          const {repos} = this.props.location.state.repos;
          const repolist = repos.length ? (
              repos.map(repo => {
                  return(

                      <div className="post card" key={repo.id}>
                          <div className="card-content">

                          <Link to={'/' + repo.owner.login + '/' + repo.name} onClick={() => this.props.enterIssues('repos/' + repo.owner.login + '/' + repo.name + '/issues')}>
                              <span className="card-title">{repo.name}</span>
                              </Link>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                  )

              })
          ) : (<div className="center">no repositories for this member</div>)
          return(
              <div className="container">
              {repolist}

              </div>
          )
      }
  }
  export default repos; ```
````

Comment: Why you don't just update state for the entire app with your search result? You can use Redux or similar in order to avoid passing props to the parent component

Comment: any suggestions on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing data to `<Repo>` component. In the Repo component, you can receive the data using `props.location`

**Receive it like this**

```js
// class based component
this.props.location.state.repos

// --

// functional component
const location = useLocation();
location.state.repos
```

Also, make sure to use exact to your `/` Route

```js
<Route exact path='/' render={() => (<Addform />)} />
```

**EDIT** - Based on the comment:

Your  component doesn't seem to have router props because your `Route` in App.js is using `render`. So either wrap `Repo` component with `withRouter` or pass router props in App.js.

Like this:

```js
<Route exact path='/:username' render={(routerPros) => (<Repos {...routerPros} repos={this.state.repos} enterIssues={this.enterIssues} />)} />
```

Comment: it should work..pls share the code for Repo component

Comment: hey .. updated the answer... pls chk and let me know.

Comment: Hello, I have tried the updated code, same issue happens the location is undefined, I think that the problem is the repos component is not receiving the state as it should, I have updated the question and included repos component code

Answer (score 0):

Add a new function to your `App` component and pass it as a prop to `Addform` component. Use this function to update the state in `App` component.

```
updateRepos = repos => {
  this.setState({
    repos
  });
};
```

Pass the function as a prop

```
<Route
   exact
   path="/"
   render={() => <Addform updateRepos={this.updateRepos} />}
 />
```

Then call the function in your `fireSearch` function

```
fireSearch = username => {
  axios
    .get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username + "/repos")
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        repos: res.data
      });

      // update repos in App.js
      this.props.updateRepos(res.data);

      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: "/" + username
      });
    });
};
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ganguly-42nvs?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: thank you, this solution works well, however the issue I have faced as I moved the "firesearch" function from app component to "addform" component, I need this to work without any functions in the main App component